# What happens to internal storage and shared preferences when android app is being updated?

Tags: android

I want to know whether files that I copied to internal storage will also be updated or sharedpreferences files? They area removed when you uninstall app, but what happens when they are updated through Play Store?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update will not remove any files or preferences saved by the app. Unless you intentionally program your update such that it does that.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not touch your internal storage files nor shared preferences on application update. They are left in the same state that they were when application was terminated prior replacing by updated version

Comment: so i have to update this files in first onCreate of new version?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove sharedpreferences is deleting application data, uninstall or do it programmatically as you can see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Look at the methods **clear()** and **remove(String key)**